# rust-docの使い方が分からない（該当ドキュメントを探すもrustdocに埋もれて出てこない）

Tags: rust

Rubyの`ri`コマンドと同じコマンドラインリファレンスはないものかと思い`dnf search rust doc`を走らせると`rust-doc`というパッケージが引っ掛かり、パッケージの説明にも「Documentation for Rust」と書いてあるのでインストールしたのですが、このパッケージに関する詳細（どのように使うのか）が調べてみても見つかりませんでした。いくら調べても見つからず困っています。この問題の解決法をご存知の方居られますでしょうか？

Comment: 参考: [oxidoc is a command-line interface to Rust documentation](https://github.com/Ruin0x11/oxidoc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RustにはRubyの`ri`のようなコマンドライン向けのドキュメントリーダーはありません。RustではHTML形式のドキュメントをWebブラウザで閲覧します。

`rustup`でRustをインストールしたなら、以下のコマンドを実行すると、ローカルのPC上にインストールされたドキュメント（HTMLファイル）をWebブラウザで開けます。

```
$ rustup doc          # https://doc.rust-lang.org/ と同じ内容のページが開く
$ rustup doc --std    # https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/index.html  と同じ内容のページが開く
```

このドキュメントはPCがネットに繋がっていなくても閲覧できます。

`rustup`によるRustのインストール方法については、[こちらのページ](https://doc.rust-jp.rs/book/second-edition/ch01-01-installation.html)を参照してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。モダンな言語は全てriに似たリファレンスをサポートしているのかと思っていました。これからはrustupからドキュメントを使って行くことにします。回答していただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

`dnf`コマンドを使っているということはOSはFedoraでしょうか？

`rpm`コマンドに`-ql`オプションを指定して実行するとインストールしたパッケージに含まれるファイル一覧が確認できますが、`rust-doc`の中を確認してみるとHTML関連のドキュメントがメインで、特に実行コマンドは含まれていないようです。

```
$ rpm -ql rust-doc
/usr/share/doc/rust/ 以下にドキュメントがインストールされる
```

```
$ rpm -ql rust-doc | grep bin/     # 特に実行コマンドは含まれない
```

インストールされたドキュメントをブラウザから参照する使い方になるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: すみません！！-qlオプションの存在を今知りました。私の勉強不足です、すみません！！